# Setting member variables to null improperly

Tags: c++

I think I'm declaring everything correctly yet I'm getting undeclared identifiers in lines 22-26 in main.cpp. I'm also getting this = is ambiguous in line 12-16 in my employee.cpp. I also have a weird expression must have pointer to object type for salary in line 55 of employee.cpp. I'd really appreciate any help since my school doesn't have a tutor at the moment.

```
//Employee.h

using namespace std;

class Employee {
private:
public:
    string FirstName;
    string LastName;
    string DisplayFirstName;
    string DisplayLastName;
    string DisplaySalary;
    string SearchName;
    float Salary;
    Employee( string FirstName, string LastName, float Salary )
    {
            setFirstName(FirstName);
            setLastName(LastName);
            setSalary(Salary);
    }
    string setFirstName(string FirstName);
    string setLastName(string LastName);
    float setSalary(float Salary);
    void ReadFile(ifstream& MyinFile, string FirstName, string LastName, float Salary);
    string EmployeeSearch(string LastName[], string SearchName);
    void DisplayEmployee (string DisplayFirstName, string DisplayLastName, string DisplaySalary);
    Employee();
};

//Employee.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "Employee.h"

using namespace std;

string setFirstName(string FirstName)
{
**FirstName = NULL;** //ambiguous error
}
string setLastName(string LastName)
{
**LastName = NULL;** //ambiguous error
}
float setSalary(float Salary)
{
Salary = 0.0;
}
void ReadFile(ifstream& MyinFile, string FirstName, string LastName, float Salary)
{
char exit_char;
int MaxSize;
int count = 0;

MyinFile.open("employee.dat"); 
    if (!MyinFile)
    {    //no
        cout << "Can't open input file." << endl; //Tests the right file.
        char exit_char;                         //End Program
        cout << "Press any key to exit" << endl;
        cin >> exit_char;
    }
    for(count = 0; count < MaxSize; count++)
    {
        MyinFile >> LastName[count];
        MyinFile >> FirstName[count];
        MyinFile >> **Salary[count];** //error
    }
MyinFile.close();
}
string EmployeeSearch(string LastName[], string FirstName[], float Salary, string SearchName, string DisplayFirstName, string DisplayLastName, string DisplaySalary)
{
    cout << "Please enter the name of the employee you would like to search." <<  endl;
    cin >> SearchName;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        if (LastName[i] == SearchName)
    {
        DisplayFirstName = FirstName[i];
        DisplayLastName = LastName[i];
        DisplaySalary = **Salary[i];**  //error
    }
    else 
        cout << "Could not find employee." << endl;
    }
};
void DisplayEmployee (string DisplayFirstName, string DisplayLastName, string DisplaySalary)
{
cout << DisplayFirstName << "   ";
cout << DisplayLastName << "    ";
cout << DisplaySalary << endl;
};

//Main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "Employee.h"

using namespace std;

const int MaxSize = 100;

int main()
{
char Redo;          //Input a character to redo the program
ifstream MyinFile;
cout << "Your Salary Machine\n\n";
Employee  Employee;
Employee.ReadFile(**MyinFile, FirstName, LastName, Salary**); //undeclared identifier error
do
{
    Employee.EmployeeSearch(**LastName[], SearchName**); //undeclared identifier error
    Employee.DisplayEmployee(**DisplayFirstName,DisplayLastName,DisplaySalary**); //undeclared identifier error
    //Asks user if they want redo the program
    cout << "Would you like to redo the program?\n";
    cout << "Please enter Y or N: \n";
    cin >> Redo;
}while(Redo == 'Y' || Redo == 'y');

return 0;
}
```

The program is written to read a file that has a first and last name then salary 
then be able to type in the last name of whoever is in the file and it will display the name and salary and then repeat. I'm suppose to use a constructor to initialize the first and last name as NULL and then the salary as 0.0. I'm also supposed to use get and set member functions.

Here are the errors:

```
------ Build started: Project: Lab3Project, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
Main.cpp
\\psf\home\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\csci112\lab3project\lab3project\main.cpp(22): error C2065: 'FirstName' : undeclared identifier
 \\psf\home\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\csci112\lab3project\lab3project\main.cpp(22): error C2065: 'LastName' : undeclared identifier
\\psf\home\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\csci112\lab3project\lab3project\main.cpp(22): error C2065: 'Salary' : undeclared identifier
\\psf\home\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\csci112\lab3project\lab3project\main.cpp(25): error C2065: 'SearchName' : undeclared identifier
\\psf\home\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\csci112\lab3project\lab3project\main.cpp(25): error C3861: 'LastName': identifier not found
\\psf\home\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\csci112\lab3project\lab3project\main.cpp(26): error C2065: 'DisplayFirstName' : undeclared identifier
\\psf\home\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\csci112\lab3project\lab3project\main.cpp(26): error C2065: 'DisplayLastName' : undeclared identifier
\\psf\home\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\csci112\lab3project\lab3project\main.cpp(26): error C2065: 'DisplaySalary' : undeclared identifier

Employee.cpp
\\psf\home\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\csci112\lab3project\lab3project\employee.cpp(12): error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous
      c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring(772): could be  'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =(_Elem)'
      with
      [
          _Elem=char,
          _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
          _Ax=std::allocator<char>
      ]
      c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring(767): or       'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =(const _Elem *)'
      with
      [
          _Elem=char,
          _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
          _Ax=std::allocator<char>
      ]
      while trying to match the argument list '(std::string, int)'
 \\psf\home\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\csci112\lab3project\lab3project\employee.cpp(16): error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous
      c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring(772): could be 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =(_Elem)'
      with
      [
          _Elem=char,
          _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
          _Ax=std::allocator<char>
      ]
      c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring(767): or       'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =(const _Elem *)'
      with
      [
          _Elem=char,
          _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
          _Ax=std::allocator<char>
      ]
      while trying to match the argument list '(std::string, int)'
\\psf\home\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\csci112\lab3project\lab3project\employee.cpp(40): error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
\\psf\home\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\csci112\lab3project\lab3project\employee.cpp(55): error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
```

Comment: Did you `#include <string>`?

Comment: And add hints to your code which line is line 22, i.e., mark the lines where the error occurs.

Comment: @BrettHolmes where in your code did you include it? Make sure to include it in the Employee.h file.

Comment: @joseph I added it but now they the errors just changed to undefined.

Comment: Why do the setters return things? They can be void. As your parameters have the same name as the members, you will need to use `this->LastName = LastName` to differentiate them.

Comment: Title changed to reflect solution or major problem within the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It looks like you need to do a lot of work to improve your code. First, you should put all your header files on Employee.h. This will be useful wherever you decide to include Employee.h, all of its header files will also be included, so you do not have to included them again.
- In C++ you can define your variables as pointers or reference. Please learn the difference between pointers (*pointer), double pointers *(***doublepointer) also known as array pointer, reference (&reference) and variables (variable). You should also learn about making a dereference to a pointer such as pointer (**pointer).
- Learn the deference between a class, a function or a variable **Definition** and its **Declaration.** This is important especially with your current assignment problem.
- You have an Employee class and if you are a starter; Header files are used for constructor, destructor, member variables and member functions definition. Whereas the .cpp files are used for constructor, member functions and non-member functions declaration. Most of the time a declaration for destructor does not include anything much, however this is where you delete pointers.
- In C++ you have to manage memory, otherwise you will have memory leaks with your pointers. So whenever you define a pointer (*pointer) you should delete it on your destructor. You are missing a destructor in your header file. You need to define one.
- You should define and/or declare the constructor in your header file like this. There is really no point of calling SetFirstName(), setLastName(), setSalary() in your constructor. These methods should be used only in the MAIN class. And to set class member variables, do this.

  ```
  Employee( string FirstName, string LastName, float Salary )
  this.FirstName = FirstName;
  this.LastName = LastName;
  this.Salary = Salary;
  ```

  }
- Include a class destructor

  ```
  ~Employee(){
  }
  ```
- Your SET functions are meant to set member variables only and should not return anything. Instead of returning a string they should be void. Like this.
- Set functions definition.

  void setFirstName(string FirstName);
  void setLastName(string LastName);
  void setSalary(float Salary);
- Define and declare GET functions.

  string getFirstName() { return FirstName;}
  string getLastName() { return LastName;}
  float getSalary() { return Salary;}
- In your .cpp files you should declare your set functions among other member functions you have defined so far in your Employee class. Like this.

  void Employee::setFirstName(string FirstName){
  FirstName = FirstName;
  }
  void Employee::setLastName(string LastName){
  LastName = LastName;
  }
  void Employee::setSalary(float Salary){
  Salary = Salary;
  }
- This Readfile function reads a file of this format example; first line; John Garry 100.50, next line; Michael Shawn 250.80 etc. And stores it in a vector of Employees.

  typedef std::vector < Employee > EmployeeType
  EmployeeType account;

  void ReadFile(ifstream& MyinFile, string FirstName, string LastName, float Salary) {
  string st;
  float n;

  while(MyinFile >> st) {
  this.setFirstName(st);
  this.setLastName(MyinFile >> st);
  this.setSalary(MyinFile >> n);
  account.push_back(this);
  }
- Search employee function. It searches by the First Name only.
- You should also learn about arrays and array pointers in C++.

  string Employee::EmployeeSearch(string LastName, string FirstName) {

  cout << "Please enter the name of the employee you would like to search." <<  endl;
  cin >> SearchName;
  string st = "No Such Employee";
  string s = " ";

  Employee *employ;

  for(int i = 0; i < account.size(); i++){
  employ = account.at(i);
  if(SearchName == employ->getFirstName()){
  std::cout << employ->getFirstName() << " " << employ->getLastName() << " " << employ->getSalary() << endl;
  st = "";

  st.append(employ.getFirstName());
  st.append(s);
  st.append(employ.getLastName());
  st.append(s);

  std::ostringstream ss;
  ss << employ.getSalary();
  string so(ss.str());
  st.append(so);
  return st;
  }
  }
  return st;

  }

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line in your main.cpp:

`Employee.ReadFile(**MyinFile, FirstName, LastName, Salary**); //undeclared identifier error`

Where did `FirstName`, `LastName`, and `Salary` come from? They were never declared in the scope of `int main()`. This is why you have undeclared identifier errors.

I'm not sure why your `Employee::ReadFile` member function takes those last three arguments. It should read in from a file and set `this.FirstName`, etc, not the arguments that have been passed into the function.

This should get you more on the right track:

```
// In header file, replace ReadFile prototype with:
void ReadFile(ifstream& MyinFile);

// In implementation file, replace ReadFile with:

void ReadFile(ifstream& MyinFile)
{
    char exit_char;
    int MaxSize;
    int count = 0;

    MyinFile.open("employee.dat"); 
        if (!MyinFile)
        {    //no
            cout << "Can't open input file." << endl; //Tests the right file.
            char exit_char;                         //End Program
            cout << "Press any key to exit" << endl;
            cin >> exit_char;
        }
        for(count = 0; count < MaxSize; count++)
        {
            MyinFile >> this->LastName;
            MyinFile >> this->FirstName;
            MyinFile >> this->Salary;
        }
    MyinFile.close();
    }

// In main.cpp, replace the current call to Employee.ReadFile with:
Employee.ReadFile(MyinFile);
```

This probably will not solve all of your issues but it is a start.

Comment: I thought it was sufficient to declare them only in my .h

Comment: Declaring them in your header file declares them on a class itself. When you call the member function from main.cpp, you are calling it with locally scoped variables.

Comment: @BrettHolmes, I have updated this answer to get you a bit closer. Try it out, report back, and go from there.

Comment: oh ok I see now. I changed the arguments in Employee::Readfile, but I don't understand what you're saying with the this.FirstName.

Comment: In your header file, when you say `string FirstName`, you are declaring a variable on an instance of the class. In main.cpp, when you do  `Employee  Employee;`, you are creating an `Employee` instance. That instance has its own variables `FirstName`, etc. In the `ReadFile` member function, we use `this.FirstName` to say, set the `FirstName` variable of this specific instance of this class. More details [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_this_pointer.htm). Also, my C++ is rusty, it should be `this->` not `this.`

Comment: It still says this-> can only be used with a nonstatic member function.

Comment: Hi Brett- it seems we've resolved your undeclared identifiers and this comment set is getting lengthy. Please start a new question regarding the use of `this`, and we can go from there. I believe it is because of the `using namespace std;` in your Employee implementation file, and your member functions do not define the Employee namespace.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it did resolve your initial errors with undeclared identifiers.